# BigQuery v0.28 ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(46 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(46 bytes read))

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I'm trying to migrate our BigQuery client library to version 0.28. Now when I'm trying to get a table reference, it fails with a `ChunkedEncodingError`. Here is my code:

```
def table_exists(client, table_reference):
    from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound

    try:
        client.get_table(table_reference)
        return True
    except NotFound:
        return False
```

We are using GAE Standard Environment. Could this be a problem with the requests library?

Comment: Possibly: https://github.com/wooyek/flask-social-blueprint/issues/18 `google-cloud-bigquery` uses the `requests` library under the hood. You may wish to try the API client library instead when running from App Engine standard. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same `ChunkedEncodingError` error when using [google-cloud-bigquery](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/) package with a deployed App Engine Standard with Python.

This is a problem of urllib3 with Google App Engine. As you can see in [this link](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#google-app-engine):

> ... if you’re using the Standard environment then you either have to use urllib3.contrib.appengine’s AppEngineManager or use the Sockets API

I used the Sockets API, which consists on adding the following to your app.yaml file:

```
env_variables:
  GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'true'
```

You have the [official google Sockets Python API docs here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/)

After that you can just redeploy and it should work.

Also there is a latest version for google-cloud-bigquery (0.30.0), try that instead of the 0.28.0 if you keep getting some error.